# Gruchestein Effect?

Tags: magnetic-fields, terminology, gravitational-waves

I overheard that name in a conversation, but not very clearly.

I can't find anything on Google, probably because of my spelling is completely wrong.

Does anybody knows about an effect with a similar sounding name?

Apparently, it is connected with one solution of General Relativity, where light passing through magnetic field can create gravity. That's all I know about it, but I would like to read more.

In Chinese literature this is called Synchro Resonance effect.

Comment: The self-interaction of electromagnetic waves is extremely small and it will lead to production of matter way before anything relevant to gravity happens.

Comment: All I am looking for is a reference, so I can read more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the Gertsenshtein effect. It is the theory that light passing through a strong magnetic field will produce a gravitational wave.

Answer (score 1):

The Gertsenshtein effect is the conversion of an electromagnetic wave into a gravitational wave, on passing through a strong magnetic field. It is a real effect in classical field theory, but very weak in practice.

The 1961 paper by M.E. Gertsenshtein ("Wave resonance of light and gravitational waves") was expanded on by Ya. B. Zel'dovich in a 1973 paper ("Electromagnetic and gravitational waves in a stationary magnetic field"). This paper also describes the inverse effect - the conversion of a gravitational wave into an electromagnetic wave - which was dismissed by Gertsenshtein as "hardly of interest" in the last line of the 1961 paper.

In a uniform background magnetic field with transverse component |B|, the length over which a gravitational wave is converted into an electromagnetic wave - and vice versa - is:

$L = \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{\epsilon_0 G}} \frac{c}{|B|}$

This is in SI units.
For a background magnetic field of B = 10 microGauss = 1 nano Tesla, that's a length scale of L ~ 700,000 MegaParsecs (by my calculation - please check!)

The conversion can be thought of as a "beating effect" caused by a small difference in the wavenumber of the two eigenmodes, in the background field. Each eigenmode is a mixture of an electromagnetic and gravitational wave travelling together in tandem at a phase velocity v, with v slightly above and slightly below c for the two eigenmodes.

Despite being very weak, the process may be relevant in the early universe, and it can possibly be used to constrain the strength of coherent magnetic fields and/or the gravitational wave spectrum before decoupling: see "Potential of Radio Telescopes as High-Frequency Gravitational Wave Detectors" by Domcke and Garcia-Cely [Phys. Rev. Lett. 126, 021104 (2021)].

Answer (score -1):

The conversation you heard was likely in regards to some much-hyped fake news (some of which is resurfacing now) about patents for High Frequency Gravitational Waveform Generators, Room Temperature Super Conductors, Inertial Mass Reduction Device, or maybe even the Micro Encabulator.

Whether or not it's a real theory, I'm not educated enough to discern - and the accepted answer (and comment) clearly demonstrate Poe's law.

I can't tell if John Rennie there is actually trying to be helpful... by literally rephrasing your question as an answer, rewording it ever so slightly into the actual direct quote you got 90% right... or if he's in on the joke that those who know keep secret and those who don't just have to wonder about.

The only places that seem to reference the Gertsenshtein effect, as far as I've been able to tell in my searches, would likely be classified as obvious hoaxes by almost anyone with a few AP- or College-level physics classes. Wikipedia mentions it but...

The Turbo Encabulator and Signetics Write Only Memory are hallmark examples of widespread inside jokes that were perpetuated for years.

It's more or less the pranksters analog to the Mandela Effect - except that the hundreds of thousands of people joining in on the experience *know* that it's a prank and by crazy cosmic coincidence they all just happen to either get such a kick out of it to decide to keep it alive on purpose, or to not care enough to object.

P.S. Having gone back and looked at CuriosOne's comment, I'm about 78% sure that it's about as a real as a snipe. The phrasing tipped my conspiratorial-satire-o-meter. In fact, it makes me wonder if the OP isn't in on it too...

So Uncanny Valley. Much Wow.

Comment: Feel free to downvote, but at least provide a source that isn't Turbo Encabulator.